# Undesired effect on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Anybody having an idea why I'm getting [this strange effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skrMe.jpg) (near the red arrow on screenshot) while hovering my left/previous button? . I don't get the same hover effect when hovering the right wing button? Also, this issue is present on Google Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer/Firefox?

My website is [www.petasos.be](https://www.petasos.be).

I've added the button via the following code:

```
/* Add wingRight */
span.next_nav {
    background-image: url(https://www.petasos.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/wingRight.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 40% 40%;
}

/* Add wingLeft */
span.prev_nav {
    background-image: url(https://www.petasos.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/wingLeft.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 40% 40%;
}

/* Hide fa-icons */
.carousel-control i {
    display: none;  
}

/* No border */
.carousel-control .next_nav, .carousel-control .prev_nav {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: I can't see the issue on my Chrome

Comment: I cannot see it either

Comment: That makes three of us, vs the one of you. Hehe.

Comment: Chrome 59 Cannot replicate. Does the issue occur if you open the website in a new incognito tab?

Comment: @Ihazkode For me, it also occurs if I open the website in an incognito tab.

Comment: Thanks for checking all, that's very strange... My Chrome version is 59.0.3071.115 (official build) (32-bits).

Comment: Ok, just to rule out caching, try a new incognito *window*

Comment: Does this only occur when you are logged in? Try clearing your site cache then view it in a browser you have no login session with.

Comment: @Ihazkode still having the issue with a new window instead of tab.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I also thought it was related to being logged in, but it also occurs when being not logged in.

Comment: @BarrieO I think that rules out caching. Your next best bet is to try to track it down in dev tools.